# ios native audio to speed up without skip

Tags: ios, audio

I have been using the Native Audio code from iOS to speed up a song's tempo/bpm. However, it skips each time there is a change. I have seen apps like DJ Apps, that can change the tempo without a skip.

How can this be accomplished? Or does anyone know the correct library to use, preferably cordova implemented?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like changing of [rate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer/1388846-rate) didn't work for you?

I think you can use `AVAudioEngine` and play with the pitch of audio (using [AVAudioUnitTimePitch](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiounittimepitch)). Or [AVAudioUnitVarispeed](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiounitvarispeed). Simply attach them to your engine. (`engine.attach(pitch)` or `engine.attach(speed)`). Don't forget to declare speed or pitch outside `play()` function or you will not be able to change properties during the playback.